# Homeomorphy of a surface

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology

I am studying graphs on surfaces (i.e. maps). Their definition is below:

> We call **map** a representation $(X,\mathcal{D})$ of a finite connected graph $\Gamma=(V,E)$ in the topological surface $X$ such that:
>
> - $V\subset X$
> - edges are represented as curves on $X$ that intersect only in vertices
> - $X\setminus \Gamma$ is the union of a finite number of topological discs called **faces** of $\mathcal{D}$.

The following graph is given as a counterexample: [image]. I cannot see what "face" number $1$ is homeomorphic to.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. If anything, face 2 simply appears to be a disc. Face 1 on the other hand, is a torus with a disc and two closed arcs (extending from the disc) removed. But notice that the complement of the disc and arcs is homeomorphic to just the complement of the disc.

Comment: Face number 2 *is* a topological disc; face number 1 is not. This is a counterexample because the requirement is (or should be) that every component of $X \setminus \Gamma$ be a topological disc.

Comment: Yes, I have made a mistake. I was wondering about face 1, I corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Face $1$ is not a topological disk because it is not contractible. (It's homotopy equivalent to a punctured torus which has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$.)